# asp.net Entity Framework "Insert" statement conflicted with FOREIGN Key Constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have been working on a project using the ASP.NET web forms using the individual-authentication settings which uses Entity Frameworks to create users on the table AspNetUsers.

So I have created a new class called `Department` which has a `deptId` as the primary key. I have tried modifying the IdentityModels.cs code to add the `deptId` as a foreign key within AspNetUsers.

The code below is what I added to try and get the foreign key implemented.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    public string isVerified { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to customer
    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int deptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

         // Add custom user claims here
         return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public object User { get; internal set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I then get the following error when trying to register from the line

```
 IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
```

The error is as follows

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Departments_deptId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "aspnet-WebEnterprise-20190201040106", table
>   "dbo.Departments", column 'deptId'. The statement has been terminated.

Is there anything I'm doing obviously wrong or missing that's causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518995/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Identity - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269127/mvc-identity-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @VDWWD hmm, the fix for that say's that no table with that key exists, although I have a departments table that has the deptId as a primary key. and it's trying to be a foreign key in users. I don't understand why it doesn't work still?

Comment: You are trying to insert an id that does not exist in the departments table, it is as simple as that. Debug the value before inserting an see if it is what you expect it to be

Comment: I dont get what you mean by this? I tried to debug but unsure of what to look out for there.

Comment: look at the created ApplicationUser instance before the SaveChanges() call. its deptId property will not be set (be equal to 0) or have a value that is not equal to the PK of any Department object in your database.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro how would I go about setting it to an existing value in the department table?

Comment: @zeearebee you have to have a department referenced, because the FK is not nullable. I suspect it is already loaded and tracked in the context, in which case you can just set it in the navigation property and relationship fixup will do the rest. If not, you'll have to query the database to find the PK of the department you'll want to see referenced.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I already have the FK's , and the FK in aspnetusers is not nullable, and the PK in Dept is not nullable